# Sass Error Indefined mixin

Tags: sass

I am trying to use a mixin with a custom function. But I have always receive the same error.

```
error sass/app.scss (Line 58 of sass/_grid.scss: Undefined mixin 'responsive-columns'.)
```

My function is :

```
@mixin responsive-columns($suffix:''){

@for $i from 1 through $columns{

    .col#{$suffix}-#{$i}{

        width : $i / $columns*100%;}

}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  The provided code compiles with a parse error.

Comment: [works for me](http://sassmeister.com/gist/4ce56c5731702dc7e2a4) - must be some other problem with the rest of your file.  Mind including it? I'd suggest running the file through a linter to see if you can pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem. I think it is a stupid one. 
First I have to add :

```
 @import "compass"
```

in my scss file.

Then in my terminal I have to use 
`compass watch` instead of `sass --watch sass_folder:css_folder`